# Regarding the computation on lyapunov function for stability

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, lyapunov-functions

I’m trying to find a suitable lyapunov function for my paper and come accross this paper about SIR model where they used $V(x,y)= (S-S^1)^2 + (I-I^1)^2$ where $S^1$ and $I^1$ are endemic equilibriums. Here’s the link to the paper:

https://www.math.lsu.edu/system/files/Project%202%20Final%20Paper.pdf

Now, based from the paper given that $V(x,y)= (S-S^1)^2 + (I-I^1)^2$,

\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
dV(x,y)= 2(S-S^1)S’ + 2(I-I^1)I’
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\tag{2}
dV(x,y)= -\frac{2}{S^1}(S-S^1)^2 - \frac{2}{I^1}(I-I^1)^2
\end{equation}

With that, I’m very confused on how the transformation from equation # 1 to equation #2 happened. Can someone help me with this?? Thanks a alot in advance

Here’s the SIR equation used in the paper:
\begin{equation}
S’= \Lambda -\frac{\beta S}{N}-\mu S
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
I’= \frac{\beta S}{N}-(\mu + \gamma)I
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
R’= (\gamma + \mu)I - \mu (N-S)
\end{equation}

Where

\begin{equation}
N= S+I+R
\end{equation}

Also,
\begin{equation}
S^1= \frac{\Lambda ^2}{\mu (\beta + \Lambda)}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
I^1= \frac{\Lambda \beta}{ (\beta + \Lambda) + (\mu + \gamma)}
\end{equation}

Comment: Can you give the SIR equations that you are working with?

Comment: I added the equation in the main question @SimonKuang

Comment: The idea is exactly the same as in my [old answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2709845/lyapunov-function-for-predator-prey-system/2710690#2710690), I will leave the details to you.